# Ruby on rails app debug and develop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I have been in Ruby on Rails for a while. Now I clone a very nice project from GitHub and i want to debug it with RubyMines.

Can someone please sugest me how do i proceed further? Do I start with Controllers? or Models? or Route.rb file?

I want to understand the app thoroughly and develop the next version with new GUI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your breakpoints wherever you want, in your models, controllers, or views. Then just run the debugger and go to the app in your browser. Whenever the application hits the part of the code where you set your breakpoint, it will stop and then you can go back to RubyMine and debug accordingly. It's really a fantastic feature.

Let me know if you if you're having any trouble with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Have one question. So if I want to start with Login page, meaning I want to put breakpoint whenever I run Localhost:3000 and take me to the login page. So do I have to put break point in Controller or at Model? The app has around 8 to 10 controllers and used many APIs.

Comment: Put the breakpoint in the controller in that case. So your login page probably goes to the new action in your sessions controller or something like that I'm guessing. Just put the breakpoint there.

Answer (score 0):

When I am getting familiar with a rails project, I will typically set breakpoints at the controllers and step through the code as requests get to the controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i do dissection(de-code) of the code?